# networkd DNS issues (cannot resolve pip name)

Tags: dns, systemd-networkd, raspberry-pi-os

I have configured my pi0w's wifi as per [my own answer to this other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113521/120864) (and [this great answer by Ingo](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/120864) that it's based on) to utilise both AP and Client modes.

Everything generally works fine, however when trying to install pip packages, the name cannot resolve.

After some initial digging, I also can't `ping google.com`, although I can `ping 8.8.8.8`

I have tried adding `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/network/interfaces` and also adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf`

I'm a bit lost where to dig further.

Any help is really appreciated as I currently can't get any pip packages. Thanks!

Edit:

For `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved.service` I get:

```
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question 2.debian.pool.ntp.org IN A: signature-expired
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question org IN DS: signature-expired
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question org IN DNSKEY: signature-expired
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.org IN DS: signature-expired
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question pool.ntp.org IN DS: signature-expired
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question 3.debian.pool.ntp.org IN AAAA: signature-expired
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question debian.pool.ntp.org IN SOA: signature-expired
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question 3.debian.pool.ntp.org IN DS: signature-expired
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question 3.debian.pool.ntp.org IN SOA: signature-expired
Jul 13 00:34:58 raspberrypi2 systemd-resolved[198]: DNSSEC validation failed for question 3.debian.pool.ntp.org IN A: signature-expired
```

Edit 2:

For `resolvectl status` I get the following under wlan0, which looks ok

```
Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
                      fdd0:462a:9688:0:8272:15ff:fee7:df78
```

...although under `Global` section, DNSSEC is not supported:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: yes
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: no
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got there in the end.  I added the following to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (as opposed to `/etc/resolv.conf` as I was previously)

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
FallbackDNS=1.1.1.1 9.9.9.10 8.8.8.8 2606:4700:4700::1111 2620:fe::10 2001:4860:4860::8888
#Domains=
#LLMNR=yes
#MulticastDNS=yes
DNSSEC=allow-downgrade
#DNSSEC=true
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=udp
```